# Burninate [3rd-party] and [third-party] tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

All of the following tags are ambiguous, applied to a variety of questions and do not provide any useful information:

- [third-party](/questions/tagged/third-party) and [3rd-party](/questions/tagged/3rd-party)
- [third-party-controls](/questions/tagged/third-party-controls) and [3rd-party-controls](/questions/tagged/3rd-party-controls)
- [third-party-api](/questions/tagged/third-party-api)
- [third-party-code](/questions/tagged/third-party-code)
- [3rd-party-library](/questions/tagged/3rd-party-library)

I suggest we burninate them all after closing off-topic questions.

[Open Questions to close or re-tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B3rd-party%5D%20or%20%5Bthird-party%5D%20or%20%5Bthird-party-controls%5D%20or%20%5B3rd-party-controls%5D%20or%20%5Bthird-party-api%5D%20or%20%5Bthird-party-code%5D%20or%20%5B3rd-party-library%5D%20closed:no)